# Jinja2 to display image in browser

Tags: google-app-engine, django-models, jinja2

mymodel.url is textproperty(string) which is something like this

```
<a href ='http://www.abc.com'><img src='http://xyz.com/></a><img src="http://www.abcdefd.com" />
```

In index.html, if I use `{{mymodel.url}}`, I will see the html code in my browser. In otherwords, jinja2 consider `{{mymodel.url}}` as string.

```
<a href ='http://www.abc.com'><img src='http://xyz.com/></a><img src="http://www.abcdefd.com" />
```

I want to see the image in my browser. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indicate to jinja2 that this content is "safe" to display in a browser as HTML

```
{{mymodel.url|safe }}
```

[HTML Escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping)

> When generating HTML from templates, there’s always a risk that a variable will include characters that affect the resulting HTML. There are two approaches: manually escaping each variable or automatically escaping everything by default.